# Earth orbit plot Python

Tags: python, simulation, orbital-mechanics

I am completing a project on planetary motion in Python and the first task is to write a code for the orbit of earth around the sun. This is what I have so far:

```
def earth_orbit(rEar,v0):
    
    #r0 = xEar[0] = rEar 
    #v0 = vyEar[0] = np.sqrt(mu/rEar) 
    
    #Set parameters:
    N = 365                     # Earth days in a year
    dt = 1.00/N                 # Time Step: Fractions of a year - 1 Earth day (i.e. 1/365)
    mu = 4*np.pi**2             # Gravitational parameter 

    #Create an array, for all variables, of size N with all entries equal to zero:
    xEar = np.zeros((N,))
    yEar = np.zeros((N,))
    vxEar = np.zeros((N,))
    vyEar = np.zeros((N,))

    # Initial Conditions:
    xEar[0] = rEar                   # (x0 = r, y0 = 0) in AU
    vyEar[0] = v0                    #units: AU/yr

    #Implement Verlet Algorithm:
    for k in range(0,N-1):
        rEar = (xEar[k]**2+yEar[k]**2)**0.5
        vxEar[k+1] = vxEar[k] - (mu*xEar[k])/((rEar)**3)*dt
        xEar [k+1] = xEar[k] + vxEar[k+1]*dt
        vyEar[k+1] = vyEar[k] - (mu*yEar[k])/((rEar)**3)*dt
        yEar [k+1] = yEar[k] + vyEar[k+1]*dt

     #Plot:
    a = plt.plot(xEar, yEar, 'go', markersize = 1, label = 'Earth trajectory')
    plt.plot(0,0,'yo', label = 'Sun positon')        #yellow marker for the sun
    plt.plot(xEar[0],0,'bo', label = 'Earth initial positon')  #dark blue marker for earth's initial position
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlabel ('x')
    plt.ylabel ('y')
    
    return a, xEar, yEar
```

This works well, however for subsequent parts of the project I've been told that I shouldn't use AU for this base code as it'll cause difficulties. I've tried changing the gravitational parameter and putting the inputs in standard units but the graph becomes just 2 dots (the values of `xEar` and `vyEar` remain constant) instead of a circular orbit and I don't know why this is?
[image: This is the output]

Comment: IIUC, you have a working function, so try changing it incrementally towards your intended version and test after every small step, to see what causes the problem.

Comment: Could the issue be simply that you have changed the dimensions (by many orders of magnitude if you have changed from AU to metres) but haven't changed your initial values? I've been trying to get your code working and I'm too lazy to figure out what a sensible value for the parameters would be so I've just been guessing and so far I haven't achieved anything resembling an orbit. (EDIT: it occured to me as I wrote this that given the units, 1 and 2*Pi would be the obvious choice of initial values and I now have a circular orbit)

Comment: I tried to change the initial values as well as the gravitational parameter, I just don't understand why when changing all from AU to km or m it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1):

Due to the definition of the gravitational constant, when you change the length unit, you have to change the value of `mu` by the cube of the scaling factor.

I pulled the definition of `mu` outside of the function for convenience.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def earth_orbit(rEar, v0):

    #Set parameters:
    N = 365      # Earth days in a year
    dt = 1. / N  # Time Step: Fractions of a year - 1 Earth day (i.e. 1/365)

    #Create an array, for all variables, of size N with all entries equal to zero:
    xEar = np.zeros((N,))
    yEar = np.zeros((N,))
    vxEar = np.zeros((N,))
    vyEar = np.zeros((N,))

    # Initial Conditions:
    xEar[0] = rEar                   # (x0 = r, y0 = 0) in AU
    vyEar[0] = v0                    #units: AU/yr

    #Implement Verlet Algorithm:
    for k in range(0, N-1):
        rEar = (xEar[k]**2+yEar[k]**2)**0.5
        vxEar[k+1] = vxEar[k] - ((mu * xEar[k]) / (rEar**3)) * dt 
        xEar [k+1] = xEar[k] + vxEar[k+1]*dt
        vyEar[k+1] = vyEar[k] - ((mu * yEar[k]) / (rEar**3)) * dt 
        yEar [k+1] = yEar[k] + vyEar[k+1]*dt

     #Plot:
    a = plt.plot(xEar, yEar, 'go', markersize = 1, label = 'Earth trajectory')
    plt.plot(0,0,'yo', label = 'Sun positon')                  # yellow marker
    plt.plot(xEar[0],0,'bo', label = 'Earth initial positon')  # dark blue marker
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlabel ('x')
    plt.ylabel ('y')

    return a, xEar, yEar


# average distance earth-sun (1 AU) in meter
au_to_m = 149_597_870_700.

mu = au_to_m**3 * 4 * np.pi**2  # Gravitational parameter 

earth_orbit(au_to_m, np.sqrt(mu / au_to_m));
```

[image: orbit plot]

Comment: This is helpful, however I am a bit confused about the figure you have used for v0 here? One of the questions on the project is to verify you find a closed orbit when the initial position is (0,rEar) and tangential initial velocity (0, 29.8km/s) however I've tried to input this and the output is just a horizontal line, so I'm not sure on the correct way to test this

Comment: @178971 I got the expression `np.sqrt(mu / au_to_m)` from the comment about `v0` near the top of your original code, just inserting `au_to_m` for `rEar`, since this is the earth's orbit radius in meters. Note that the time unit in your code is years, so the initial y velocity you want to verify is `29800 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25` meters per year, which turns out to be practically the same as the value I used.

Comment: Oh yes I see now, thank you for your help! A final question I have is that I've been looking at similar codes people have done to simulate the orbit of earth and the majority of them include the mass of the sun, so I'm a bit worried about not including it, however since this code works I'm confused where I would implement it if I need to?

Comment: @178971 If you want to explicitly use the masses of earth and sun, you can use Newton's formula for the gravitational force, and F = m*a to update the velocities. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation

Comment: I've been having a go at this but my output is just 2 dots. I was trying to include a calculation for the acceleration within the for loop but I don't think this is right, do you have any tips on how to implement this into my code?

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. In general, the orbit is elliptical, so the distance and thus the acceleration may change, so this calculation has to be inside the for loop. Maybe you are again being thrown off by the units. Remember the SI unit for acceleration is m/s^2, but your code uses years rather than seconds.

Comment: This is nice but is there a way to get the values of the orbit back? Let's say we plot a maneuver, how can I get all the state vectors (timeseries) of the displayed maneuver ?

Comment: @zd5151  You could add `vxEar` and `vyEar` to the `return` statement of the `earth_orbit()` function, and then when you call the function, assign its return values to a suitable tuple, e.g. `a, x, y, vx, vy = earth_orbit(...)`.